# Which real functions have their higher derivatives tending pointwise to zero?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathrm C^\infty\!(\Bbb R)$ be the space of infinitely differentiable functions $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$, and define the subspace$$A:=\{f\in\mathrm C^\infty\!(\Bbb R):(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f^{(n)}(x)=0\},$$where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$th derivative of $f\;(n=0,1,\dots).$ Clearly all polynomial functions are in $A$. Are any others?

**Edit:** Alfonso has answered this question well, but is there any characterization of $A$ in terms of familiar types of function?

Comment: Some uniformly convergent example: $f(x)=\sin(a x)$, where $0<a<1$.

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen has just classified $A$ in the best way possible. If you want to find a different way to express the elements of $A$, start with Hagen von Eitzen's result.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva No, mine are just the *analytic* examples. I'm only *almost* sure that this is complete

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : Hm, nice remark, I didn't pay attention. So you found the intersection of $A$ with the space of analytic functions, we need to find what's outside of it now.

Comment: @jkn: I don't see that $A$ is closed under multiplication. For example, take Alfonso's function: $f(x)f(x)=\mathrm e^x,$ so $ff\notin A.$

Comment: @JohnBentin yes you are right - I dunno what I was thinking.

Comment: @jkn : When speaking of such questions when the domain is $\mathbb R$, multiplication is usually not behaving nicely. It is an exercise in a first course in analysis to show that the product of continuous functions remains continuous, but you cannot add "uniformly"s in this sentence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider an analytic function 
$$\tag0f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n.$$
As $f^{(n)}(0)=a_n$, a *necessary* condition for such $f$ to be an example is that $a_n\to 0$.

But $a_n\to 0$ is also *sufficient*.
Indeed, with $b_n:=\sup_{k\ge n} |a_k|$ we have $b_n\to 0$ and hence
$$\begin{align}|f^{(n)}(x)|&= \left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_{n+k}}{k!}x^k\right|\\
&\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{|a_{n+k}|}{k!}|x|^k\\
&\le b_n\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}|x|^k\\&=b_ne^{|x|}\to 0. \end{align} $$
(Note that the calculation for $f^{(0)}(x)$ shows that $f$ is entire to begin with).

Comment: This looks pretty close to being a complete answer. There is just a slight niggle about whether the elements of $A$ are analytic. It seems obvious, but the proof eludes me. Anyway, it is time for me to accept your answer!

Answer (score 7):

$$f(x)=e^{x/2}$$
$$f^{(n)}(x)=2^{-n}e^{x/2}$$

Comment: Of course, this is true for any $e^{\alpha x}$, $-1<\alpha<1$, and also for a more uniform result $$\left| \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \sin (\alpha x) \right| \le \alpha^n$$

Answer (score 0):

Another example would be the reciprocal function:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{1}{x}=(-1)^n\frac{n!}{x^n}$$

By extension, $\ln(x)$ is another example, because $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: What is $f(0)$?

Comment: What if $x=0.00000000000000000001$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I see. It's not continuous or differentiable at 0.

Comment: Not only that. The limit never goes to zero.

Comment: The function is not defined at zero, therefore does not belong to the space. This should be the first problem you notice.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Yes, I'm pretty sure that's what I said in the above comment.

Comment: @ZettaSuro : I'm pretty sure it's not. You said it wasn't *continuous* nor *differentiable*. I'm saying it's not *defined*. This means that $f : \mathbb R \backslash \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb R$ is the largest domain for which $f(x) = 1/x$ makes sense. To say that $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ you need to say what $f(0)$ means and it is not done by writing $f(x) = 1/x$. Same issues with the logarithm.